# Can I transfer Hex to another target after it died even if it had Animate Dead cast on it after?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Say I cast hex on a target, and curse the creature with disadvantage to ability checks with dexterity.

After the creature is killed by dropping to 0 hit points, a member of my party casts animate dead on it to turn it into a zombie. Since my target dropped to 0 hit points on my turn, before Animate Dead was cast on it, can I still transfer the Hex to another creature at any time on a subsequent turn of mine? (And can it be a different curse?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can move the spell onto a new target.

Raise dead does not mention anything about any existing spell effects, nor does hex mention anything about a target being revived.

No, you cannot change the ability check, you can only move to the spell to a new target.

> ...choose one ability when you cast the spell.

When you move the spell it is simply cursing a new target, you are not recasting the spell.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can choose a new target.

*Hex* states:

> If the target drops to 0 hit points before this spell ends, you can
>   use a bonus action on a subsequent turn of yours to curse a new
>   creature.

While *Animate Dead* has the target requirement of:

> Choose a pile of bones or a corpse of a Medium or Small humanoid
>   within range. Your spell imbues the target with a foul mimicry of
>   life, raising it as an undead creature. The target becomes a skeleton
>   if you chose bones or a zombie if you chose a corpse...

The target cannot be a corpse while it still has hit points. It has to have dropped to zero This satisfies the requirements to allow you to re-target *Hex*. Further, the original target is no longer the original creature. It has gone from being a creature, to a corpse (an object), and then to an undead creature. There is no condition I know of that sticks with a creature over such a radical transformation.

*Hex* does not allow you to choose a new curse, only a new target.

Answer (score 1):

**You can choose a new target**

Hex says:

> If the target drops to 0 hit points before this spell ends, you can use a bonus action on a subsequent turn of yours to curse a new creature.

There is a trigger "the target drops to 0 hit points before this spell ends"; once this occurred "you can use a bonus action on a subsequent turn of yours to curse a new creature" - it is irrelevant if the creature is dead (with or without undead animation), unconscious or even subsequently healed and still fighting. You have the trigger in your pocket to use whenever you want.